# How to create a menu with background images for list items?

Tags: 7, routes, theming

How would you make a menu that have a different background image for each `<li>` element in the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. Use the module http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes (beta 1 is out for Drupal 7)
2. Give each menu item a CSS ID or class that needs an image
3. Use CSS to assign background images to the menu items

Using this method, no PHP coding is required, and the menu images become content editable by your authors (once the CSS images have been setup).

Answer (score 0):

also:
Use the module http://drupal.org/project/imagemenu

A simple module which allows you to create menus from image files. Supports title (displayed when hovering over a menu item), alt text, weights and optional mouseover behaviour.